# Plot Coordinates on Google maps using google API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am a fresher... literally...Please keep that in mind while answering this question :-) Can anyone please explain step by step procedure to:

"Plot given coordinates on google maps using the google maps API.  Each point when plotted on google maps should have a custom icon"

Comment: Where do you get the coordinates from? Where do you get the custom icon for each marker? You should provide all information regarding your question.

Comment: I did write a code which plots and displays custom icon. Thank you so much for your response though!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add [marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) to your coordinates.

```
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
```

You can [customize](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#icons) each marker. Icons should set their icon properties to an object of type Icon, and icon objects define an image. They also define the size of the icon, the origin of the icon, and the anchor where the icon's hotspot should be located.

Comment: I did write a code which plots and displays custom icon. Thank you so much for your response though!